QT3D Scene3D geometry renderer not visible
I am trying to use QT3D to display a point cloud. In order to test the rendering, i created a simple QT3D project with a main.cpp file and a main.qml file. I understand that QT3D is different from QTQuick3D and in order to use QT3D types within a QTQuick application, these types need to be contained within a Scene3D object, hence the following setup.
Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.2 as QQ2
//! [0]
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
//! [0]
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.15
import QtQuick.Scene3D

QQ2.Window {
    visible: true
    Scene3D {
        visible: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        Entity {
            id: rootEntity
            property int pointCount: 10000  // Number of points in the cloud
            function generateVetexData() {
                 // var vertexData = new Float32Array([  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
                 //                                   ]);

                var vertexData = new Float32Array(pointCount * 9);  // 9 floats per vertex

                        for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
                            var x = Math.random() * 20 - 10;  // Random x position between -10 and 10
                            var y = Math.random() * 20 - 10;  // Random y position between -10 and 10
                            var z = Math.random() * 20 - 10;  // Random z position between -10 and 10
                            var r = Math.random();            // Random red color value
                            var g = Math.random();            // Random green color value
                            var b = Math.random();            // Random blue color value
                            var nx = 0.0;                     // Normal x
                            var ny = 1.0;                     // Normal y
                            var nz = 0.0;                     // Normal z
                            //var intensity = Math.random();    // Random intensity

                            // Set the vertex data
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 0] = x;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 1] = y;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 2] = z;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 3] = r;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 4] = g;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 5] = b;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 6] = nx;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 7] = ny;
                            vertexData[i * 10 + 8] = nz;
                        }

                return vertexData;
            }

            RenderSettings {
                id: renderSettings
                activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                    clearColor: "black"
                    camera: camera
                    showDebugOverlay: true
                }
            }

            // Camera
            Camera {
                id: camera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 75
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9
                nearPlane: 0.01
                farPlane: 1000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 10.0, -50.0)
                upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 10.0)
            }

            // Light
            DirectionalLight {
                id: light
                worldDirection: Qt.vector3d(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
                intensity: 1.0
            }

            TorusMesh {
                   id: torusMesh
                   radius: 5
                   minorRadius: 1
                   rings: 100
                   slices: 20
               }

            // Material
            PhongMaterial {
                id: phongMaterial
                ambient: "gray"
                diffuse: "white"
                specular: "lightgray"
                shininess: 50.0
            }

            Buffer {
                id: vertexBuffer
                usage: Buffer.ReadWrite
                data: rootEntity.generateVetexData()
            }

            // Geometry for point cloud
            GeometryRenderer {
                id: pointCloudRenderer
                instanceCount: 1
                primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Points
                geometry: Geometry {
                    id: pointCloudGeometry
                    attributes: [
                        // Position attribute
                        Attribute {
                            name: defaultPositionAttributeName
                            attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                            buffer: vertexBuffer
                            byteOffset: 0
                            byteStride: 36 // 3 (position) + 3 (color) + 3 (normal) = 9 floats * 4 bytes
                            vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                            vertexSize: 3
                            count: rootEntity.pointCount
                        },

                        // Color attribute
                        Attribute {
                            name: defaultColorAttributeName
                            attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                            buffer: vertexBuffer
                            byteOffset: 12 // 3 (position) * 4 bytes
                            byteStride: 36 // 3 (position) + 3 (color) + 3 (normal) = 9 floats * 4 bytes
                            vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                            vertexSize: 3
                            count: rootEntity.pointCount
                        },

                        // Normal attribute
                        Attribute {
                            name: defaultNormalAttributeName
                            attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                            buffer: vertexBuffer
                            byteOffset: 24 // 3 (position) + 3 (color) * 4 bytes
                            byteStride: 36 // 3 (position) + 3 (color) + 3 (normal) = 9 floats * 4 bytes
                            vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                            vertexSize: 3
                            count: rootEntity.pointCount
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }

            // Transform
            Transform {
                id: transform
                scale3D: Qt.vector3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
            }

            // Camera Controller
            OrbitCameraController {
                camera: camera
            }

            components: [renderSettings, pointCloudRenderer, transform, torusMesh, light]
        }
    }
}

Main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    if (QOpenGLContext::openGLModuleType() == QOpenGLContext::LibGL) {
        format.setVersion(3, 2);
        format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    }
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setSamples(4);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

My build kit is QT6.7, a lot of examples online seem to be using old QT versions and quite a few things seem to have changed. When I run this app, nothing gets rendered, just a blank screen. Is this setup correct, or am I missing something.

To answer my own question, I needed to add the phongMaterial element to the components list, now I can see the points displayed.
components: [renderSettings, pointCloudRenderer, transform, phongMaterial, light]

